# Disabling tool tips for html list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

Having Html list like ,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/A/" title="This is A">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="/B/" title="This is B">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="/C/" title="This is C">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="/D/" title="This is D">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="/E/" title="This is E">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="/F/" title="This is F">F</a></li>  
<ul>
```

Want to disable tool tips for all the li elements of this ul . Not every ul of the document.
How can i do it with jquery ?

Comment: can't you add an id/class to the ul

Comment: then `$('#myul a').removeAttr('title')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the title attribute (which is "responsible" for the tooltips) from your elements with jQuery in the following way:

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li><a href="/A/" title="This is A">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="/B/" title="This is B">B</a></li>
    <li><a href="/C/" title="This is C">C</a></li>
    <li><a href="/D/" title="This is D">D</a></li>
    <li><a href="/E/" title="This is E">E</a></li>
    <li><a href="/F/" title="This is F">F</a></li>  
<ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("ul#mylist li a").removeAttr("title");
    });
</script>
```

Edit: Wrapped jQuery to prevent executing before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Set tooltip on all elements with:

```
$('*').tooltip();

And disable with

$('ul li a').tooltip('disable');
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean to remove the title attribute?

You can do that using this:

```
$('ul li').attr('title', '');
```